# how to extract the data based on two columns condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a complete dataset **(336663,675)**. I have extracted the best 50 features of the dataset that is cumulative data. Now my dataset is (336663,51). I want to extract the data based on the Chassis_id column for example(B-689653) and Target column that has value(0,1). I have calculated a unique **Chassis_id** that is 6675. I want to extract the 500 unique chassis_id who have target value at least (1) no duplicate value of 1 and it also has 0 target value for the same chassis_id. My dataset looks like.

```
chassis_id  lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_x_index_1    lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_y_index_1    lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_y_index_10   lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_y_index_11   lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_y_index_12   lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_y_index_2    lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_y_index_3    lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_y_index_6    lx_pmu_p1fwm_engine_speed_torque_h_y_index_7    ... lx_pst_p1em9_12_pmairdryercartridgeresetvehicl  lx_pst_p1em9_13_pmairdryercartridgeresetengine  lx_total_vehicle_distance_rule_based    x_pst_p1c2o_365_vdlcomprtotaltime_log   age_months  age_years   index   slx_pfe_0008_nbr_of_gearshifts  lx_psc_p1bby_total_fuel_consumption target
0   B-689653    2021.500000 1781.000000 134.000000  116.500000  199.500000  1887.000000 411.500000  227.000000  203.000000  ... 3.966420e+08    2.576429e+07    407768.285714   2.886354e+07    49  4.1 59  1.097197e+06    168443.547071   0
1   B-689653    3189.833333 2122.000000 157.000000  136.000000  231.000000  2204.000000 467.000000  340.833333  234.000000  ... 4.218106e+08    2.747081e+07    472178.233333   3.344411e+07    56  4.7 73  1.258732e+06    194795.161889   0
2   B-689653    1271.538813 1131.897717 98.544292   86.657534   147.538813  1337.124201 296.357991  166.649315  149.873059  ... 2.797100e+08    1.720796e+07    313343.510638   2.057084e+07    37  3.1 34  8.198200e+05    129537.235780   0
3   B-689653    751.934132  641.526946  62.425150   54.425150   94.095808   869.185629  189.610778  109.347305  96.263473   ... 1.501943e+08    8.925830e+06    202014.000000   1.287711e+07    22  1.8 4   5.264317e+05    81851.484950    0
4   B-689653    882.568862  784.449102  73.419162   65.419162   110.263473  1001.760479 225.179641  127.455090  113.724551  ... 1.958617e+08    1.174458e+07    231647.428571   1.469532e+07    25  2.1 11  6.159844e+05    93664.449960    0
5 rows × 52 columns
```

I have used the code but its not working on it.

Main dataset of shape **(336663,675)**

```
data = pd.read_csv("prodcut_data.csv", low_memory=False, na_values='?')
```

I have extracted the Best 50 features data

```
data1 = pd.read_csv("LVD-F_selc_F_extr.csv", low_memory=False, na_values='?')
```

I have chassis_id in other dataframe So, I have concatenate it with extract best 50 features data.

```
data2 = pd.concat([data.chassis_id, data1], axis=1)

mask = (data2[data2['target'].eq(1)].duplicated(subset['chassis_id']).reindex(data2.index,fill_value=False))

data2 = data2[~mask]
print(data2)
```

This code return me all dataset. not the desired one

Comment: I'm confused. You want to get all the rows that have a particular chassis id and have targer either 0 or 1? Something like: `data1[data1.chasis_id=='B-689653' & (data1.target == 0 | data1.targer == 1)]`

Comment: @F trias. I want all chassis_id that have at least target value is 1(means no duplicate value of 1 in that chassis_id) and  0 also for that chassis_id, not just this particular Id.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more regarding this 'target value at least (1) no duplicate value of 1 ' ?

Comment: @baby_yoda I just want target value 1 for chassis_id one value not duplicate values.

Comment: So, you want to find chassis_id where the target value is one, but not all chassis_id (since there would be duplicates), just unique chassis_id numbers. Right?

Comment: @ baby_yoda yes, I want target value 1 at least one. yes, there will be duplicates but I want just 1 target value and rest target value that is 0 with that chassis_id that also I need.